# Get Confusion Matrix by group in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, subset, confusion-matrix

I am trying to get a confusion matrix by age group. So I want to get a subset of true value and predicted value for each age group. 
Specifically, here is my code(I have run a lightgbm model and got the prediction defined as y_predict) :

```py
y_new=np.column_stack((test_age_group,y_test,y_predict))
test_age=pd.DataFrame(y_new, columns=['age_group','test','predict']) 

age_group=["21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51-60","60-80"]
```

I am thinking to run a for loop: for every category in the `age_group`, return their index and get the corresponding `y_test` and `y_predict` and then get the confusion matrix and plot.

Not sure if it is an efficient way and am wondering what function do I need to do the above mentioned for loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution now: `data21_30=test_age[test_age.age_group=='21-30']`

A more efficient way to define all the data categories with less lines of code is welcome!